# Mongo is not account specific

Tags: ssh, redhat, shell, mongodb, accounts

I have mongo running on my system however I can access all my databases/collections from other peoples accounts. Can I secure specific collections? How do I block access to my collections but not cut them off of the mongo shell?

Answer (score 1):

For authentication purposes you need to start mongod with --auth option (Considering the user and passwords already created.)

For further info please refer this links

[mongodb user authentication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication)

[Quick tip to setup users in mongodb](http://learnmongo.com/posts/quick-tip-mongodb-users/)